# Static objects on server will create any problems?

Tags: java

I have a Server program Server.java which can handle multiple clients and i am using static objects in it for connection termination and etc.

If two clients are connected to the server and one client closes the connection and will it results in connectionlost for second client?

Will Static objects in two instances of server share same address space?

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static fields or class variables` are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a `class` variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a `class` variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes to all the questions you have asked. Static objects will share the same address and basically be the same object. If one request closes the connection executing the operation on the other will be un-defined. You will be better off using a static connection pool.